# How to put heads of columns, on group, with detail data below, using one dataset, in fastreport?

Tags: fastreport

I'm stack on building report in fastreport 4.15
I'm trying print two group of data (normal - horizontal band), and next group on vertical band (to get headers of columns), and finally details on data band.
My current report:
[image]
current result:
[image]
what I need:
[image]
How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use multi-column stretched TfrxMasterData band
Place TfrxSubreport on it. Set TfrxSubReport.PrintonParent to True
See a sample here: [test.fr3](https://dropmefiles.com/o4PCW)

Comment: One of top reason of problem is, i must use one dataset (named DIETY), and I can't change this datasets or add new. When I add sub-report build on the same dataset, then i get all data in single sub-report (there is no return to master report after end of group, because this is the same dataset).

Comment: In this case you should calculate and set Engine.CurY, Engine.CurX positions in the script before start of each of sub-group. This was a more complex task then add second (detail) dataset

Comment: Nice, i will try this. Do i need vertical band on this solution ?

Comment: No, you need 2 or 3 datasets if you use vertical bands